# Using a Do-Loop, to read a column of data (numerical & string) and filter the numbers as output into another file

Tags: arrays, fortran, dummy-data

I have an output file, single column, where each 7th line is a string and the others numerical (something like below)

```
998.69733    
377.29340    
142.22397    
53.198547    
19.743515    
7.5493960    
timestep:  1
998.69733    
377.29340    
142.22047    
53.188023    
19.755905    
7.5060229    
timestep:  2
998.69733    
377.29337
```

I need to read this data into another file, omitting the text and keeping only the numbers and tried a loop to allocate a dummy for my string but I get an error as it does not recognize (AI).

```
DO 10 I = 1, 1000
 IF (MOD(I,7) == 0) THEN 
  READ (8, FMT= '(AI)') dummy
 END IF
  READ (8,*) val
  WRITE (9,*) val
10 CONTINUE
```

(8 - input file and 9 - output file allocation)

I am quite new to Fortran and spent a lot of time surfing for a solution or at least a similar problem but did not find anything. I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to skip the seventh lines, you could do "read (8, '(A)' )  dummy" where dummy is declared as a character string (i.e., "character (len=80) :: dummy").   It won't matter than some of the characters are letters and others numbers.

P.S.   The modern was to write loops is "do", "end do" ... no need for line numbers and continue statements.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use list-directed input with an empty input item list.
Also, the seventh line gets read twice in your loop. Put the read and write of `val` in an `ELSE` section, or, alternatively, us the `CYCLE` statement:

```
DO I = 1, 1000
  IF(MOD(I,7) == 0) THEN 
    READ(8,*)
    CYCLE
  END IF
  READ(8,*) val
  WRITE(9,*) val
END DO
```